# How to display google play games services popups('Welcome','Unlock Achievement') in my react native application

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am building a RN android game. I have a native UI Component where i want to show the play games 'Welcome Popup' if the user is signed in on starting the app. Also I have a react native navigation modal where I want to show the 'achievement unlocked' popup. I haven't found any helpful documentations on the internet which could help me achieve it . Can anyone please help??